# How to set dynamic document.title?

Tags: javascript, document

I have following javascript. There are 2 constant elements by ID - title and artist. I want to appear those in browser tab, so i think with document.title. row 51.
If you wonder what for - I need this to grab that metadata from the browser tab (artist and title) from a broadcast software on another PC. It's only in localhost. That's the only way.
The metadata appears on index.html but i can't grab this from there, i can only grab this from browser tab. It's so specified by this application i got.

Very thankful for your help in advance.

Javascript:

```
/**
 * OBS Overlay
 */
const SERVER = `ws://${location.hostname}:9090`;

/**
 * Formats the track name.
 * @param {TrackInfo} track
 */
const formatTitle = (track) => {
  if (!track.title) return '';
  return track.title.toUpperCase();
};

/**
 * Formats the track artist.
 * @param {TrackInfo} track
 */
const formatArtist = (track) => {
  if (!track.artist) return '';
  return track.artist.toUpperCase();
};

const updateTrack = (track) => {
  const title = formatTitle(track);
  const artist = formatArtist(track);
  const titleEl = document.querySelector('#title');
  const artistEl = document.querySelector('#artist');
  const overlay = document.querySelectorAll('.fade');

  if (titleEl.innerHTML === title && artistEl.innerHTML === artist)
    return;

  // Fade out the old track title.
  overlay.forEach((el) => {
    el.style.opacity = 0;
  });

  // Fade in the new track.
  setTimeout(() => {
    titleEl.innerHTML = title;
    artistEl.innerHTML = artist;
    overlay.forEach((el) => {
      el.style.opacity = 1;
    });
  }, 1000);
};

 
     // Set title of document
     document.title = 'test';
   
  
  

// WebSocket connection to Triode Twitch DJ.
const ws = new WebSocket(SERVER);

// Send heartbeat to Now Playing every 5 seconds.
setInterval(() => {
  const state = ws.readyState;
  if (state === 1) ws.send(JSON.stringify({ event: 'ping' }));
}, 5000);

/**
 * Take in an IPC message from the main process and update the DOM.
 *
 * @param {IpcEvent} event IPC message from the main process
 */
ws.onmessage = (event) => {
  const data = JSON.parse(event.data);
  updateTrack({
    title: data.title,
    artist: data.artist,
  });
};
```

index.html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>NOW PLAYING:</div>
    <div>
    <span id="title" class="fade">NO TRACK LOADED</span> - <span id="artist" class="fade">NO ARTIST LOADED</span>
    </div>
    <script src="default.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the problem? Does the title not get set to `test` ?

Comment: could you also share your html

Comment: Have added. I don't want to appear 'test' LOOL. I want to appear track artist and title. When i play a track on a play-software this default.js gets it and send to index.html . It works super. But i want also to have it in browser tab.

Comment: if your scrapping the page you cant use js to set the title, if you need current playing etc make an API that can be called

Comment: why not put the `document.title = title+' - '+artist;` inside the `// Fade in the new track.` part?

Comment: It works! You won a coffee machine!! Thank You!

Comment: I have another question - how can i send this "title" and "artist" to external xml? f.i http://server.com/index.xml